# Why is Half-Cauchy, Half-Student-t as prior for variance parameters better than a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, variance, prior

[Gelman](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations) often refers to using half-cauchy or half-student-t distributions for variance parameters. Why is it better than using a vague normal distribution such as N(0,10)? Can somebody explain me the mathematical or statistical intuition behind it?

Comment: There is no "better" or "worse" prior in my opinion (imho). However, priors with fat tails have less of a tendency to drive the posterior towards a concentrated region of the parameter space unless the prior and the data truly agree.

Comment: You mean half-normal?